# When does iOS check retain count table on runtime

Tags: ios, runtime, automatic-ref-counting, retain, retaincount

I read that (from a book written by Kazuki Sakamoto and Tomohiko Furumoto) on runtime iOS maintains a `hashtable` with object's address as key and that object's retain count as value.

Like below:

```
key(object's addr)       value(reference count)

0x7fff59a7ba88           2

0x7fa84b4b2c10           0
...
```

And iOS runtime would check the table once a while to see if any key with value equals zero, meaning some objects should be released, then iOS would remove that key-value pair from table and call `dealloc` to release the object's memory.

If this theory is correct, then my question is that at what time, with what frequency system would check the `reference count hashtable`? Each `runloop`? Or iOS wouldn't check the table at all but only it's automatically done?

UPDATE:

I just corrected my description which should have nothing to do with ARC or MRC, it's more about reference counting on runtime.

Comment: This doesn't sound like ARC, it sounds like an autorelease pool.

Comment: @rmaddy actually it is the basic mechanism of ARC on runtime, otherwise how would system track the retain count of each object? It must store the retain counts somewhere in some data structure so it can check and operate. It's using an `ARC` table, but when? That's my question.

Comment: No. Tracking the retain count has nothing to do with ARC. Objects had a retain count long before ARC. The only thing ARC adds is the automatic insertion of calls to `retain` and `release` by the compiler. ARC and MRC code are the same at runtime. When an object's retain count goes to zero, it is deallocated (ARC or MRC).

Comment: @rmaddy yes, the table I mentioned is not specific to ARC or MRC, but that's how iOS do memory management, and how iOS retains or releases objects on runtime according to the retain counts from compiler. I will edit my question for correction.

Comment: A similar case would be the `weak table`, which maintains object's addresses as keys and their `weak` variables that are pointing to them as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of behaviour sounds more like garbage collection, and isn't exactly how ARC works.

ARC's behaviour is completely deterministic: it tracks the number of `strong` references to an object, and once that count hits 0, the object is immediately deallocated. You can read about the implementation details [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: I understand what ARC/MRC does during compiling, but what does iOS do under the surface during runtime for memory management? Isn't there a table to record all the memory used and reference counts? Anyway the `table` thing is read from a book.

Comment: Whenever -release is called, the runtime will check the reference count. It doesn't poll the reference count as you seem to be thinking.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It's not specific to ARC. This description equally applies to MRC as well.

Comment: You're right: perhaps I should specify that it's automatic? And that the compiler does this via objc_release() and friends?

Comment: Actually what I wanted to know is that according to @caughtinflux, whenever `release` is called, runtime would go to check the reference count. Yes, it is not specific to either ARC or MRC, it is a generic memory management idea. And I already edited my question and description to avoid any misleading here.